# Upgrade Installation confusion 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, upgrade, updates

I just tried to upgrade from 12.04LTS to 12.10...
I used the update manager and everything was going on well till my system froze up.
I had no option than to hard reboot and realized that I could not continue using the update manager. 
I used apt-get -f install and looks like installation was done successfully.
Problem is system manager still tells me I have 12.04 LTS installed but when I run 
ls_release -a in the terminal it tells me I have 12.10 installed.
I realize many things are malfunctioning and I can't update.
It says CANNOT INSTALL UPDATES: Try partial update and when I try it says cannot ugrade from quantal to precise.
I wonder if anyone has answers for me... THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` installs anything. if it didn't work try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: Actually did that. Did apt-get dist-upgrade and went to bed. WOke up and restarted the system and Voila everything is ok. 12.10 working perfectly. THanks